# Morphia logging over log4j in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, javabeans, morphia

I want to log Morphia over Sfl4j with log4j. From Morphia's documentation:

> Add this at the start of your
>   application. It is done once,
>   statically.
>   MorphiaLoggerFactory.registerLogger(SLF4JLoggerImplFactory.class);

I can't create necessary beans for above statement to get that work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the docs claiming otherwise, the class is actually called SLF4JLogrImplFactory (Logr, not Logger):

```
import com.google.code.morphia.logging.slf4j.*;

MorphiaLoggerFactory.registerLogger(SLF4JLogrImplFactory.class);
```

Comment: If you still have problems, you might just try implementing LogrFactory and Logr yourself and routing it to the appropriate log4j analogs. That's what I ended up doing, and it took all of 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a spring issue. You need to find out how to do some kind of static initialization.

Comment: Yep... I do the static initialization but I get error. I don't remember entirely but is something like "SLF4JLoggerImplFactory.class is unknown type".

Comment: Did you include the extension jar in your app? This sounds like a missing jar problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which jar I need to include for that? I've included these artifacts _logging-slf4j_ and _morphia_ from com.google.code.morphia groupId and of course the log4j dependencies.